# Drop table in Rake task in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, database-migration

I would like to arbitrarily drop all tables in my Rails app via a Rake task.

This is for testing/staging purposes, and rolling back migrations doesn't seem appropriate/necessary here.

I've got to:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
  puts "=== Deleting: #{t.to_s}"
  drop_table t
end
```

But of course `drop_table` is undefined in this context. How should I call it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer here: http://problemateek.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/drop-table-from-rails-console.html

The call just needs to be scoped under `ActiveRecord::Migration` like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table t
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is many years later, but I believe this is was `db:drop` / `db:create` and `schema:load` are for -- or maybe even `db:reset` -- to completely reset your database without migrating all the way back and then forward again.

Comment: `db:drop` worked for me. I want to drop all the databe and re-run the migrations. Thanks